# How to copy data from different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data from sheet ABC. I know the column number, start row and end row. When i try the following code it throws error. any help would be great

```
workbooks("ABC").worksheets("abc").range(cells(startrow,1),cells(endrow,1)).copy
```

Comment: without more detail this is impossible to answer! We need to see the rest of the vba. We also need details of the error - at least the error message.

Comment: Must be the source worksheet is not active! again and again ... We are not supposed to advice you to activate your worksheet before the copy statement ;)

Answer (score 0):

One liners are hard to deal with. Breaking down helps:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim startrow, endrow
startrow = 1
endrow = 10
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("stops") ' my test sheet
' copy first column to clipboard
wks.Range(wks.Cells(startrow, 1), wks.Cells(endrow, 1)).Copy
```

I think your main error was not qualifying the `Cells` reference. It might work on a single sheet, but not from another sheet or workbook.

```
Dim startrow, endrow
startrow = 1
endrow = 10
Range(Cells(startrow, 1), Cells(endrow, 1)).Copy ' of this worksheet
```